# Node Sass CSS importer with npm

Tags: css, node.js, npm, sass

Inlining css within sass is [depricated](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2362) so I try to use the npm package [Node Sass CSS importer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass-css-importer). But I can't get it to work.

I use npm directly as a build tool:

```
 "build:css": "node-sass some_path/style.scss some_path/css/glamos.min.css",
```

how do I have to rewrite this?
I thought something like:

```
"build:css": "node-sass some_path/style.scss some_path/css/glamos.min.css  --importer node-sass-css-importer",
```

I then run `npm run build:css` but that just results in the error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'path_to_repo/CssImporter'

How do I have to write this?

Comment: Have you tried installing `https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass-css-importer`?

Comment: jup. I did `npm i node-sass-css-importer --save-dev` before. But how do I activate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

They removed the deprecations, you can see it on the release notes of the last version `Removes noisey deprecation warning for @import'ing .css files`

- https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2362#issuecomment-396239814
- https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.11.0

---

It's a little confusing but if you want node-sass to inline you have to call it like this `@import "./normalize";` instead of `@import "./normalize.css";` **without the extension**, as mentioned on this issue. https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2362#issuecomment-388634848

This are the steps I followed to have it working.

```
npm instal node-sass --save-dev
```

Add to your package this script

```
"build:css": "node-sass src/style.scss dist/glamos.min.css"
```

Example `style.scss`

```
@import "./normalize";

$font-stack:    Helvetica, sans-serif;
$primary-color: #333;

body {
  font: 100% $font-stack;
  color: $primary-color;
}
```

And this is the output `glamos.min.css`

```
/*! normalize.css v8.0.1 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */
/* Document
   ========================================================================== */
/**
 * 1. Correct the line height in all browsers.
 * 2. Prevent adjustments of font size after orientation changes in iOS.
 */
html {
  line-height: 1.15;
  /* 1 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */ }

/* Sections
   ========================================================================== */
/**
 * Remove the margin in all browsers.
 */
body {
  margin: 0; }

/**
 * Render the `main` element consistently in IE.
 */
main {
  display: block; }

/**
 * Correct the font size and margin on `h1` elements within `section` and
 * `article` contexts in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.
 */
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0.67em 0; }

/* Grouping content
   ========================================================================== */
/**
 * 1. Add the correct box sizing in Firefox.
 * 2. Show the overflow in Edge and IE.
 */
hr {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  /* 1 */
  height: 0;
  /* 1 */
  overflow: visible;
  /* 2 */ }

/**
 * 1. Correct the inheritance and scaling of font size in all browsers.
 * 2. Correct the odd `em` font sizing in all browsers.
 */
pre {
  font-family: monospace, monospace;
  /* 1 */
  font-size: 1em;
  /* 2 */ }

/* Text-level semantics
   ========================================================================== */
/**
 * Remove the gray background on active links in IE 10.
 */
a {
  background-color: transparent; }

/**
 * 1. Remove the bottom border in Chrome 57-
 * 2. Add the correct text decoration in Chrome, Edge, IE, Opera, and Safari.
 */
abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: none;
  /* 1 */
  text-decoration: underline;
  /* 2 */
  text-decoration: underline dotted;
  /* 2 */ }

/**
 * Add the correct font weight in Chrome, Edge, and Safari.
 */
b,
strong {
  font-weight: bolder; }

/**
 * 1. Correct the inheritance and scaling of font size in all browsers.
 * 2. Correct the odd `em` font sizing in all browsers.
 */
code,
kbd,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, monospace;
  /* 1 */
  font-size: 1em;
  /* 2 */ }

/**
 * Add the correct font size in all browsers.
 */
small {
  font-size: 80%; }

/**
 * Prevent `sub` and `sup` elements from affecting the line height in
 * all browsers.
 */
sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline; }

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em; }

sup {
  top: -0.5em; }

/* Embedded content
   ========================================================================== */
/**
 * Remove the border on images inside links in IE 10.
 */
img {
  border-style: none; }

/* Forms
   ========================================================================== */
/**
 * 1. Change the font styles in all browsers.
 * 2. Remove the margin in Firefox and Safari.
 */
button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  /* 1 */
  font-size: 100%;
  /* 1 */
  line-height: 1.15;
  /* 1 */
  margin: 0;
  /* 2 */ }

/**
 * Show the overflow in IE.
 * 1. Show the overflow in Edge.
 */
button,
input {
  /* 1 */
  overflow: visible; }

/**
 * Remove the inheritance of text transform in Edge, Firefox, and IE.
 * 1. Remove the inheritance of text transform in Firefox.
 */
button,
select {
  /* 1 */
  text-transform: none; }

/**
 * Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
 */
button,
[type="button"],
[type="reset"],
[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button; }

/**
 * Remove the inner border and padding in Firefox.
 */
button::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner {
  border-style: none;
  padding: 0; }

/**
 * Restore the focus styles unset by the previous rule.
 */
button:-moz-focusring,
[type="button"]:-moz-focusring,
[type="reset"]:-moz-focusring,
[type="submit"]:-moz-focusring {
  outline: 1px dotted ButtonText; }

/**
 * Correct the padding in Firefox.
 */
fieldset {
  padding: 0.35em 0.75em 0.625em; }

/**
 * 1. Correct the text wrapping in Edge and IE.
 * 2. Correct the color inheritance from `fieldset` elements in IE.
 * 3. Remove the padding so developers are not caught out when they zero out
 *    `fieldset` elements in all browsers.
 */
legend {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* 1 */
  color: inherit;
  /* 2 */
  display: table;
  /* 1 */
  max-width: 100%;
  /* 1 */
  padding: 0;
  /* 3 */
  white-space: normal;
  /* 1 */ }

/**
 * Add the correct vertical alignment in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.
 */
progress {
  vertical-align: baseline; }

/**
 * Remove the default vertical scrollbar in IE 10+.
 */
textarea {
  overflow: auto; }

/**
 * 1. Add the correct box sizing in IE 10.
 * 2. Remove the padding in IE 10.
 */
[type="checkbox"],
[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* 1 */
  padding: 0;
  /* 2 */ }

/**
 * Correct the cursor style of increment and decrement buttons in Chrome.
 */
[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: auto; }

/**
 * 1. Correct the odd appearance in Chrome and Safari.
 * 2. Correct the outline style in Safari.
 */
[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  /* 1 */
  outline-offset: -2px;
  /* 2 */ }

/**
 * Remove the inner padding in Chrome and Safari on macOS.
 */
[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none; }

/**
 * 1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
 * 2. Change font properties to `inherit` in Safari.
 */
::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  /* 1 */
  font: inherit;
  /* 2 */ }

/* Interactive
   ========================================================================== */
/*
 * Add the correct display in Edge, IE 10+, and Firefox.
 */
details {
  display: block; }

/*
 * Add the correct display in all browsers.
 */
summary {
  display: list-item; }

/* Misc
   ========================================================================== */
/**
 * Add the correct display in IE 10+.
 */
template {
  display: none; }

/**
 * Add the correct display in IE 10.
 */
[hidden] {
  display: none; }

body {
  font: 100% Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #333; }
```

Comment: That's how I use it right now. But this import function of inlining css into scss will be depricated at one point.

Comment: As I can read in this comment they will keep the import as it is. https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2362#issuecomment-396239814, but they will rethink it on version 5.

Comment: Oh. really?! my build tools complain all the time. Well then I guess I leav it at that.

Comment: Just to be sure they removed the deprecations, you can see on the release notes of the last version `Removes noisey deprecation warning for @import'ing .css files` https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.11.0

Comment: can you ad this as an answer so I cal close this question?